# Observing UITextField.editing with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex, rx-cocoa

I want to observe the property `UITextfield.editing`. I'm using this code:

```
self.money.rx_observe(Bool.self, "editing").subscribeNext { (value) in
    print("")
}.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

But in the process of running, it's only performed once. How do I solve this，please

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Don't observe the `editing` property, because it's not just a stored property.  It's defined as:

```
public var editing: Bool { get }
```

So you don't know how UIKit is actually getting that value.

Instead, use `rx.controlEvent` and specify the control events you're interested in, like so:

```
textField.rx.controlEvent([.editingDidBegin, .editingDidEnd])
    .asObservable()
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        print("editing state changed")
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 16):

For **RXSwift 3.0**

```
textField.rx.controlEvent([.editingDidBegin,.editingDidEnd])
        .asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: {
            print("editing state changed")
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: But in this case, you can't distinguish which of the event is happened. For Swift 4.x also workes.

Comment: It's an option set so you can be specific such as `.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidEnd)`

Answer (score 3):

Since RxSwift 4.0, there is two specific control events : `textDidBeginEditing` and `textDidEndEditing`

You can used it like this :

```
textField.rx.textDidEndEditing
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                print("End of edition")
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)


textField.rx.textDidBeginEditing
                .asObservable()
                .subscribe(onNext: {
                    print("Start of edition")
                }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: this is UISearchBar's events, not for UITextField

Comment: Yes. This is for `UISearchBar` events. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With most recent Rxswift you can use it as:

```
yourTextField
        .rx
        .controlEvent(.editingDidEnd) // you can also use other controlEvents
        .withLatestFrom(yourTextField.rx.text)
        .observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe { [weak self] text in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            print("when editing didEnd, my text is \(text)"
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

By using *.withLatestFrom* you also can get the text that is written on the time depends on your defined controlEvent.