# RxSwift replacement shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want use UITextfield with RxSwift. My goal is allowing/not input character in User keyboard and removing character from copy paste, I need handle UITextfield's delegate  "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" with **RxSwift**.

How to implement with **RxSwift**?

I am using RxSwift version 4.
Case 1: 
Input from keyboard: A123
Process from RxSwift : Accept 123 (not allowing NumberPad)
Output : 123

Case 2:
Input form Copy Paste from Contacts: \U202d1111111111\U202c
Process from RxSwift : remove all control character, accept 1111111111
Output: 1111111111

If in general we can use shouldChangeCharactersInRange , but how to use with RxSwift?

Comment: Maybe this can help you...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627440/observing-uitextfield-editing-with-rxswift

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Also, tell us what you have in `textField(textField:shouldChangeCharactersIn range:replacementString:)` already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, you should not be mutating state in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, even if you aren't using Rx. That callback is a query not a command. The textfield is merely asking you if it should perform the default behavior, not telling you to update it. The behavior you are trying to implement should be in the editingChanged action.

Since you are using Rx, the text field's `rx.text` observer is equivalent to the editingChanged action and should be used instead. The hardest part of the procedure is making sure you don't loose the user's place if they are inserting/deleting in the middle of the string.

In your viewDidLoad:

```
textField.rx.text.orEmpty
    .map(digitsOnly)
    .subscribe(onNext: setPreservingCursor(on: textField))
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Supporting global functions:

```
func digitsOnly(_ text: String) -> String {
    return text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
}

func setPreservingCursor(on textField: UITextField) -> (_ newText: String) -> Void {
    return { newText in
        let cursorPosition = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.selectedTextRange!.start) + newText.count - (textField.text?.count ?? 0)
        textField.text = newText
        if let newPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: cursorPosition) {
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, even if you are presenting the number pad keyboard, you still need some code like this because the user might have a bluetooth keyboard hooked up and thus could still enter non-numbers.

Comment: Note that `textField.text = newText`
 will not cause an event of  rx.text controlProperty. If you want to force a text event you need to manually send  valueChanged event`textField.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)`

Comment: If you want to force a text event in this situation, you are treating your view as if it was part of your model. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe text update and revert it when necessary:

```
Observable.zip(textfield.rx.text, textfield.rx.text.skip(1))
    .subscribe(onNext: { (old, new) in
        if $invalid {
            textfield.text = old
        }
    })
```

Comment: .skip only neglects a number of objects emitted first, then it starts receiving current objects, so the new and old values will be the same. However, in this case, you zip two observables that emit at the same time so it may give new as old and vice versa, depends on which fires first